# Add a class if the ajax poll takes more than x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add a class (this class put a spinner in an input, but thats not the problem) when the ajax poll takes more than x seconds (probably 1500 ms). I've tried with a setInterval and then, when the poll finishes I close the interval. But this didn't run.

I use jquery to do the ajax call and I use the property "async: false", this could be the problem? If I remove this my code doesn't run well so I need the ajax poll "sync".

Thats my code:

```
function calcvat(){
    message_timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('.js-vatinput').addClass('changing');
     }, 1000);

    if(isValidVAT()){ //In this function is the ajax
     ....
    }
}

function isValidVAT(){
...
$.ajax({
    data: {...},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false, //This could be the problem?
    url: url,
  }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    ...
    $('.js-vatinput').removeClass('changing');
    clearInterval(message_timer);
    message_timer = false;
}
....
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Where is `message_timer` declared? (Also: Don't set it to `false` when there's no active timer, set it to `0`. Also, you're using `setTimeout`, so use `clearTimeout`, not `clearInterval` [though both will work, in my experience].)

Comment: `async: false` is definitely *a* problem, it's not clear if it's the *entire* problem though. You should remove it, regardless. You also should be careful using polling as it can easily flood your server with requests. Depending on what the purpose of this code is you may want to investigate WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead, if you need to keep the server data and client UI in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `async: false` is the problem. By using `async: false`, you force the browser to suspend the main UI thread while the ajax call is being done. **No** UI updates will be allowed, **no** other JavaScript code can run, etc., until the ajax call completes.

`async: false` is never correct. At best it makes for poor UX in any case (it freezes the tab at least, and also possibly other related tabs; on older browsers [such as IE8] it froze the whole browser UI).

Remove the `async: false` and (inferring from your code) just disable sending the form / performing the action that this validation is a part of while the ajax call is pending instead.

---

Side note 1: 1.5 seconds is a long time to wonder whether something is happening. Suggest feedback within 250ms at the latest; immediate feedback is generally better.

Side note 2: I assume `message_timer` is declared somewhere. :-) If not, the code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and you'll want to declare it somewhere that both of those functions have access to it (but not, ideally, globally).